# React Router Dom useNavigate causes reload/re-render of the whole application and thereby clearing all state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-navigation

When I want to perform a programmatic forward navigation or a programmatic return navigation on button click, React Router Dom useNavigate() clears all state, redux and context and revert to initial. eg

```
<IconButton 
onClick={()=>{
  navigate(-1)
}}>
  Go back
</IconButton>
```

on clicking to return to previous page, all states on the page are reverted to initial state.
Please is there any solution?

And yes I have tried the following

```
<IconButton 
onClick={()=>{
  navigate(-1 , { replace: true })
}}>
  Go back
</IconButton>
```

and...

```
<IconButton 
onClick={()=>{
  navigate(-1 , { replace: false })
}}>
  Go back
</IconButton>
```

And none works. How do I keep the previous state when I perform a programmatic navigation?

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you are navigating using react-router's link elements or pushing to its history between `Parent and Child` elements then the state of the parent components should be preserved.
But If you are navigating between siblings then to persist the state you'll need to use some sort of storage (session storage, local storage, or reading from some DB)

Another solution would be using a Higher-order-component that would be the top-level component (Higher than react-router), so when the location has changed, you don't lose the information in the state. in another word, you have to have a general state.

Comment: Saving to local storage works but it isn’t good for a large application like this one.  I realized that it’s an issue with useNavigate hook because the previous useHistory hook works like anticipated. I researched a bit and saw that the issue had been pulled a long time ago from the repo but hasn’t been merged yet according to this thread https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7634 I follow. What other alternative do I have because switching to the legacy version 5 won’t work in our case.